# How to get substring with an unknown length

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexof

I have a string in which the table name changes every time. How to find the substring and use its value.eg

Sample string:

> Table 'ProductCostHistory'. Count 1, logical 5, physical 0

```
if (line.Contains("Count"))
{
    int index = line.IndexOf("Count");
    string substring2 = line.Substring(index, 12);
    string scancountval = substring2.Substring(11);
}
```

Now how can I do the same for table `ProductCostHistory`, where the name of the table changes every time?

Comment: Can you add some sample strings to your question?

Comment: It would help to see some examples of what the string values might be, and equally importantly, what you'd hope to get out of them. I suspect you'll be looking for `string.Split`, but it's impossible to say from what you've shown us now.

Comment: @Matthew: I just need the table name as a value. the same i am doing for the 'Count' which is easy enough but what when the name of the table changes evrytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string methods like [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx). The latter is used to find the start-index of a given sub-string. It returns -1 if it was not found, so this can also be used to avoid an additional `String.Contains`-check. It has also an overload which takes an integer to specify the character position to begin the search(used below for the `endIndex`):

```
string text = "Table 'ProductCostHistory'. Count 1, logical 5, physical 0";
int index = text.IndexOf("Table '");
if(index >= 0)  // no Contains-check needed
{
    index += "Table '".Length; // we want to look behind it
    int endIndex = text.IndexOf("'.", index);
    if(endIndex >= 0)
    {
        string tableName = text.Substring(index, endIndex - index);
        Console.Write(tableName); // ProductCostHistory
    }
}
```

Note that in  .NET strings are compared case-sensitive, if you want a case-insensitive comparison:

```
int index = text.IndexOf("Table '", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```